# React - Populating nested values is throwing error

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

First of all, I am very new to React, so please excuse my ignorance. But I am really struggling to get a piece of code to work.

First of all, the premise is that I have an array of class objects, and I am trying to incorporate them into a dictionary, where the key is a text property from that class object, and the value is an array of those objects with the property matching that key.

The idea is so that when I render the page, I can group all of those objects based on the key value.

Hopefully, this will make sense in my illustration below.

Assume that I have a class, as follows:

```
export class MyClass {
  type: string;
  description: string;
  // other class properties
}
```

And my react component receives a list of those objects:

```
export interface IMyComponentProps {
  myClasses?: MyClass[];
}

export const MyComponent: FC<IMyComponentProps > = ({myClasses}) => {
 ...
}
```

The idea is that I want to end up with a dictionary, with each key as a unique 'type' value from each class in that list, and the value is the list of classes that have that particular type.

I have spent a long while trying to get it to work, with the code below the closest I have managed. However, it falls over when trying to render the page, with a generic error.

```
export const MyComponent: FC<IMyComponentProps > = ({myClasses}) => {
  const myDictionary: {
    [key: string]: MyClass[]
  } = {};

  const populateDictionary = (myClasses: MyClass[]) => {
    myClasses.forEach(populateDictionaryItem);
  };

  const populateDictionaryItem(myClass: MyClass)
  {
    myDictionary[myClass.type].push(myClass);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    populateDictionary(myClasses);
  }, [myClasses]);
  
  return (
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Based on what I have read and how Javascript handles arrays, that should work, but it doesn't, and I am wondering if anyone is able to see what I am doing incorrectly.

Could it be that I have to inspect the dictionary first to see if the key exists, and create an empty array before the push if it doesn't? I haven't managed to work out the syntax to achieve that.

Again, apologies for my lack of experience, there are probably a few things in the code above that I am not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I now have it working.

The issue was, as I suspected, that I needed to instantiate an empty array first. After some experimentation, I did it like this:

```
const populateDictionaryItem(myClass: MyClass)
{
  if (myDictionary[myClass.type] == null)
  {
    myDictionary[myClass.type] = [];
  }
  myDictionary[myClass.type].push(myClass);
}
```

Thanks